# ckeditor doesn't show up on heroku with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ckeditor

I use ckeditor for a rails project. It works well in development env. But I deployed project to the heroku and ckeditor textarea is looks a normal textarea. there is nothing related to ckeditor. I tried this two potential solutions but both of them didn't work.

http://weichienhung.github.io/blog/2013/09/09/rails-and-heroku/ (ckeditor rake task)
http://terrybu.blogspot.com.tr/2014/07/getting-ckeditor-to-work-on-your-rails.html

what should I do?